# PYMQI with IBM MQ Client Docker Container

Tags: python, dockerfile, ibm-mq, pymqi

I have created the docker file where i am using IBM MQ Client library to install before installing the `pymqi`. But i see my docker image size become large like 4GB. Is there anyway to find  unused files and remove? Also, is there any lighter version of IBM MQ client available which uses the `python and pymqi`

here is the reference [dockerfile](https://github.com/agamjajoo/docker_ibm_mq_python/blob/master/Dockerfile)

Comment: Use the Redist client.  You can pick only what you need.

Comment: 4GB is a lot - when I last measured it (which was V8) the redistributable MQ Client was only 134MB. What exactly did you install in your docker container? Did you for example include the Java client (which isn't needed for pymqi btw)?

Comment: @MoragHughson, I have given the link of  dockerfile in my question. my base image is python:latest instead of  ubuntu. I dont have any client installed . Do you have any sample dockerfile which i can reference to compare ?

Comment: You are installing the full client with rpm.    Did you look at the Redist client instead.

Comment: @JoshMc I never used  Redist client. do u have any document which i can refer? also if u look my dockerfile i am just installing which i needed to run PYMQI

Comment: What was the difference in size of your docker file before and after the MQ install? I thought you were saying that it had increased by 4GB, but I re-read your question and I think maybe you mean that is the full size after the install?

Comment: Try Google ibm mq redist client.   Lots of info in the ibm docs.